# How do I execute Junit test case after package phase in maven?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to run my Junit on my build jar's, but maven surefire plugin executed on class file before package phase that is at test phase, is there any way to run all junit after building a jar of project.
Reason to run on build jar is to verify obfuscation of jar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution is to use the [maven-failsafe-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html) which will in the integration test phase. You need to this to your pom file:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

You should following the [conventions](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) and follow the naming conventions of integration tests:

```xml
<includes>
 <include>**/IT*.java</include>
 <include>**/*IT.java</include>
 <include>**/*ITCase.java</include>
</includes>
```

Afterwards you can run those integration tests via:

```
mvn clean verify
```

If you like to run [only unit tests](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference):

```
mvn clean test
```

Comment: khmarbaise thanks for ans, I have two concerns 1- how could I know that its taking the project obfuscates jar while run test cases, ? and 2- how can I bypass the surefire plugin ?

Comment: To take the correct jar is the job of those integration test. Skipping tests can be done via `mvn -DskipTests=true`...

Comment: Your answer is very helpful to us, however may I ask where should I put these `*IT.java` file to? I tried putting them under `src/test/` like those unit tests and then run `mvn clean verify`, however it pops up with errors like `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:...`. Did I miss something? @khmarbaise

Comment: Problem solved, since I'm using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, I should include `<configuration><classifier>exec</classifier></configuration>` in the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` section. Thank you again!

Comment: Note that the includes come within the `<plugin>`  block wrapped in `<configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

There are two phase of tests in maven, one is unit test, second is integration tests. So if You want, You should execute it in integration tests phase.