# How to test our packaged jar file behave the same with the compiled class files?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jar

We use **Maven** for managing our dependencies and **Jenkins** for CI. One problem we have right now is that our application read and write file within the built jar, it caused some issue there until we tried `InputStream/OutputStrem` for read/write. As far as I know, both Maven and Jenkins running unit tests based on the compiled class files, instead of the packaged/built jar file. So I'm wondering is it possible to run tests based on the packaged/built jar file to make sure our application behave the same both on development and production environments.

Comment: You can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019969/how-do-i-execute-junit-test-case-after-package-phase-in-maven though I'm not sure if this is what you are asking.